# Penetration testing - how to fix a vulnerability?

Tags: authentication, penetration-test

Welcome, I always wanted to ask this, how you fix/patch a vulnerability by yourself? /maybe possible duplicate, but I have not find the same, or I search the wrong way.. (sorry) /

I know a bit how to test a web_app vulnerability,and I understand how to fix them.
But let's say there's a vulnerable operation_system and I want to patch the vulnerabilities by myself and not by security updates from devs?

Or it's affect if the OS/App is open-source or closed-source? /my rights to solve the mistake in the source code../

Thank you for educational informations, we need to learn to learn something. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the application is open source, then you just need to find the sourcecode section which is responsible, fix the bug and recompile. You might want to send a patch to the maintainers of the application so they can apply it to the mainline.

When the application is closed source, then providing a patch yourself is usually practically impossible. You *could* do what the crackers do and manually edit the compiled binary with a hex editor, but this is 1. very difficult and tedious and 2. often a violation of the EULA of the software.

Sometimes you can plug a vulnerability temporarily with a firewall rule or some other middleware layer which prevents the exploitive data from reaching the application intact. Sometimes you can also temporarily fix a vulnerability by switching off a specific feature or changing a specific setting of the application (hope it's something you don't need).